# About generics and lists in java

Tags: java, list, generics

I've this simple interface:

```
public interface Transportable<T> { 
  public T getTransport();
}
```

and a lot of classes that provide implementation, ie:

```
class A implements Transportable<ATransport> {
  public ATransport getTransport() {
    ATransport at=new ATransport();
    [...]
    return at;
  }
}
class B implements Transportable<BTransport> {
  public BTransport getTransport() {
    BTransport bt=new BTransport();
    [...]
    return bt;
  }
}
```

also I've lists of transportables objects, like this:

```
LinkedList<A> aList=new LinkedList<>();
```

and I want to call the getTransport method for all elements in aList, obtaining a LinkedList, doing something like that:

```
LinkedList<ATransport> atList = getTransport(aList);
LinkedList<BTransport> btList = getTransport(bList);
```

I don't want to write a foreach for every class I have, is there a way to implement this using generics? like:

```
public <T> List<???> getTransport(List<T> list)
```

or something similar? I've tried but without luck, I think I'm missing something about generics and about the difference between using  or  etc...

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Java 8 by any chance?

Comment: Would this help? `public static <U, T extends Transportable<U>> List<U> getTransport(List<T> list)`

Comment: @arshajii, unfortunately no.

Comment: @GáborBakos, I'll give it a try. If it works would you mind to post it as an answer so I can accept it? - thank you

Comment: it works! thanks! I've to study more... can you provide some links to a clear tutorial with examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working:

```
package dummy;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

class ATransport{}
class BTransport{}
class A implements Transportable<ATransport> {
  public ATransport getTransport() {
    ATransport at=new ATransport();
    return at;
  }
}
class B implements Transportable<BTransport> {
  public BTransport getTransport() {
    BTransport bt=new BTransport();
    return bt;
  }
}
class X {
    public static <U, T extends Transportable<U>> List<U> getTransport(List<T> list) {
        List<U> ret = new LinkedList<>();
        for (T t : list) {
            ret.add(t.getTransport());
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BTransport> transportsB = getTransport(Collections.singletonList(new B()));
        List<ATransport> transportsA = getTransport(Collections.singletonList(new A()));
    }
}
```

The idea behind this is that we name the type we need and what we get. The only trick is to create as a `static` method, so the type inference is working there. (Just like in the `Collections.singletonList` call.)

Edit:
[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) is a tutorial for generics explaining the `static` method trick and some other type inference use cases. [This](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html) seems to be a useful resource for generics. The basic idea (naming the other type and using in the bound) might have a more general name that I am unaware of, sorry for not giving a reference to that.