# Hierarchies and generics

Tags: java, generics

In my application I have a model based mainly on two hierarchies of classes: the containers and the elements. The containers have references of elements through lists.
 For example consider a Java class `Child` that is subtype of `Parent` and `ElementChild` that is subtype of `ElementParent`. The elements are used as type parameters for lists and I would like that every container can add, remove and get elements from its list. These list should be as restrictive as possible, ie should contain elements placed at the same level of hierarchy (`Child` - `ElementChild`).

I know that `List<ElementParent>` and `List<ElementChild>` are not in a subtyping relation, is there a better approach than just create two different lists (`List<ElementParent>` in `Parent` and `List<ElementChild>` in `Child`) ?

In the following example I used an inherited list to show what I mean, but obviously it does not compile:

```
public class Parent {

    protected List<ElementParent> list;

    public Parent () {
        list = new ArrayList<ElementParent>();
    }

    public List<ElementParent> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void add(ElementParent element) {
        list.add(element);
    }

    public void remove (ElementParent element) {
        list.remove(element);
    }

    public void setList(List<ElementParent> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {


        public Child() {
            list = new ArrayList<ElementChild>(); // does not compile
        }

        public List<ElementChild> getList() { //does not compile
            return list;
        }

        public void add(ElementChild element) {
            list.add(element);
        }

        public void remove (ElementChild element) {
            list.remove(element);
        }

        public void setList(List<ElementChild> list) { //does not compile
            this.list = list;
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you put the relevant code up here? Which ones of your classes are generic? Sounds like none to me.

Comment: `List<? extends ElementParent>`.

Comment: @christopher: That would be a producer only list.

Comment: The generics here are the lists, each container should have a reference to a list, and the elements are the type parameters. Let me think about a clear piece of code and I'll post it.

Comment: Is it possible that a similar solution might work for you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292827/about-generics-and-lists-in-java/24293759#24293759 (introduce another generic parameter).

Comment: I updated my question with an example that shows the idea, obviously not working.

Comment: This will not work. You want to set and get, and still want covariant behaviour. You can do this with arrays, but that will cause `ClassCastException`s too. You need to find a different abstraction.

Comment: I know my example does not work, but my general idea does not seem so strange to me: the hierarchy of the elements must follow the hierarchy of the containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question demonstrates why *`List<ElementParent>` and `List<ElementChild>` are not in a subtyping relation*.

Since `Child extends Parent` and `Parent::add(ElementParent element)` method exists, it is thusly inherited to `Child`.

Now you can write:

```
ElementParent ep = ...;
Child child = ...;
child.add(ep); //perfectly legal
```

But what would that do? Add `ElementParent` to list of `ElementChild`s? And that is the reason why *`List<ElementParent>` and `List<ElementChild>` are not in a subtyping relation*.

So how to solve your problem?

Wildcards could help here, for example `List<ElementParent>` and `List<ElementChild>` both are `List<? extends ElementParent>` and you can read `ElementParent` from `List<? extends ElementParent>`, but unfortunatelly, you can't write anything to it (except `null`).

Similar with the lower bound `List<? super ElementChild>`, but on your place, i would reconsider what exactly you want to achive and if it is possible to use different approach.

Answer (score 3):

This is a thorny problem known as *covariant subtyping*. In a nutshell, it means that when you're extending (a.k.a subclassing) a class and override some of its methods you cannot change the type of the parameters of these methods. If this were allowed the compiler will not be able to make the type-safety guarantees of Java.

AFAIK  the only solution to your problem is to rely more heavily on generics. Specifically, you need to define a class which is parameterized on both the type of the element and the type of the list:

```
public class Base<E, L extends List<E>> {

  protected L list;

  public Base(L l) { list = l; }     

  public L getList() { return list; }
  public void add(E element) { list.add(element); }
  public void remove(E element) { list.remove(element); }
  public void setList(L list) { this.list = list; }
}
```

Then you can define Parent and Child as subclasses of Base, passing in the actual types for the `E` and `L` type parameters:

```
public class Parent extends Base<ElementParent,List<ElementParent>> {    
  public Parent() {
    super(new ArrayList<ElementParent>());
  }    
}

public class Child extends Base<ElementChild, List<ElementChild>> {
  public Child() {
    super(new ArrayList<ElementChild>());
  }
}
```